# Is there a name for the following property of a finite semiring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a finite semiring ($|R|<\infty)$ and let $0$ be the identity element of $(R,+)$.

Now the following property crossed my way:
$$\forall a,b\in \left(R\setminus\{0\}\right):\;a+b\ne 0\;\;\text{and}\;\;a\cdot b\ne 0\;\;$$
This means nothing else but the identity element $0$ can not be generated by the other elements in $R$. In other words, there is no zero divisor and there is no element different from $0$ with an inverse element in $(R,+)$.

Now my question: 
**This property seems not that special and so I wonder if there is a name for this property and maybe some results for the corresponding semirings?**

Comment: The obvious example of this is $\mathbb N$. What other examples exist?

Comment: @lhf: Sorry, i am interested in finite semirings. I edited my question. An example is $(P(\mathbb{Z}_n),\cup,\cdot_n)$, where $P(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is the power set of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\cdot_n$ is element-wise.